# Web Inspector on mobile Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, ios7

I'm having difficulty inspecting web pages on mobile Safari.

I'm using an iPhone 5S with the latest version of iOS 7 and the Safari nightly builds on Mac. I've also got the relevant options turned on for the iPhone and desktop Safari but my device never appears in the Develop option in Safari.

Has this feature been removed in iOS 7 or am I going mad?

**Update:** Furthermore, this seems to work fine with an iPad running iOS 7 so I've ruled out the version of iOS. And I've tried it with two different devices (both same spec, 5S) which don't work

Comment: maybe you have to add as device the iphone in the xcode organizer

Comment: I've used this feature before without needing to use Xcode in the process at all.